# system can not find the file specified

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have following method to convert pcl file to pdf through WinPCLtoPDF.exe. this exe is located in the root of my console project.

```
  public void convertToPdf(string filePath)
    {

        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        startInfo.FileName = "~/WinPCLtoPDF.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = filePath;
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();

    }
```

when I give complete physical path of this exe file, code runs successfully but when I give logical path like this

> ~/WinPCLtoPDF.exe

it gives exception

> system can not find the file specified.

please help me to specify the logical path of this exe. thank you.

Comment: Use Server.MapPath to convert the relative path to the absolute path

Answer (score 0):

The Filename path is always supposed to be a physical path but we have some helpers to map logical paths to our physical path.

```
startInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/WinPCLtoPDF.exe");
```

This should do that mapping for you.

Also Server is from the HttpContext the app is running in